# How to test form submits in Polymer 2 elements without the page refreshing

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, web-component-tester

I have a Polymer 2 "search" component that contains a form and a text input. The component handles the form submit on the form element using `on-submit="_handleFormSubmit"`, and the handling function calls `event.preventDefault()`. This works as expected when used in a real app - the form submission isn't handled by the browser and so there is no page refresh. Also, the handler creates a custom `search` event that's fired on the component. Here is its code:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">

<dom-module id="my-search">
  <template>
    <form on-submit="_handleSearchSubmit">
      <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="[[placeholder]]" value="{{searchFor::change}}">
    </form>
  </template>

  <script>
    class MySearch extends Polymer.Element {

      static get is() { return 'my-search'; }

      static get properties() {
        return {
          'placeholder': {
            type: String
          },
          'searchFor': {
            type: String
          }
        }
      }

      _handleSearchSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('search', {detail: {searchFor: this.searchFor}}));
      }
    }

    window.customElements.define(MySearch.is, MySearch);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

I'm trying to write tests for this component, but I can't seem to stop the form submit from refreshing the test page (and hence infinite test loop) when I try to test the `search` event. Here is what my test looks like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">

    <title>my-search-test</title>

    <script src="../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/web-component-tester/browser.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="../src/my-search.html">
</head>
<body>
    <test-fixture id="mySearchTest">
      <template>
        <my-search></my-search>
      </template>
    </test-fixture>

    <script>
      suite('<my-search>', function() {
        var el;

        setup(function() {
          el = fixture('mySearchTest');
        });

        test('the search event is triggered on form submit', function(done) {
          var formEl = el.shadowRoot.querySelector('form');
          el.addEventListener('search', function(event) {
            done();
          });
          formEl.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit'));
        });

      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've tried changing `formEl.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit'))` to `formEl.submit()` and the same problem occurs, although using the `submit()` approach seems to refresh the page quicker than firing the event. Also, when firing the event, I get full test output in the console (so it tells me all tests passed) before it refreshes.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How are you submitting your form in real application? I don't see any submit button.

Comment: It's just enter button pressing at the moment. The plan is probably to expose the keyup event and let other components react to key presses.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it turns out the problem is I'm likely not running tests properly.

I was running the tests by doing a `polymer serve` and accessing a page like 'http://127.0.0.1:8081/components/myapp/test/my-search.html'.

In Firefox (53.0.3 64bit Ubuntu) this is producing the infinite refreshes.

In Chrome 58 64bit Ubuntu this is working fine.

Accessing 'http://127.0.0.1:8081/components/myapp/test/' and doing a `WCT.loadSuites()` within 'index.html' to run the test works fine in both browsers, and also outputs a nice test summary in the page body.

I have no idea if the original testing method is meant to work, but when I click on an individual suite from the test index page, the URL uses a `?grep=` query string to select the test file, and this also works in both browsers, so I'm guessing not.